# How to execute C code which requires strings and file names as input through Terminal?

Tags: c, command-line, terminal

I am newbie in C language and I am writing code which works with files. But I cannot execute it through Terminal, as I will be needing to pass strings and file names through terminal commands.
P.s: I couldnt find proper solution googling myself, sorry if this question was asked before.

Here is my code:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     #define N 102
     #define n 21

     void replace(char *s, int l, int r, char *s2);

     int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
         if (argc!=5) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input format!\n");
             exit(1);
         }
         FILE *fp1, *fp2;
         fp1=fopen(argv[2], "r");
         fp2=fopen(argv[4], "w");
         if (fp1==NULL || fp2==NULL) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input!\n");
              exit(1);
         }
         char s1[n], s2[n];
         strcpy(s1, argv[1]);
         strcpy(s2, argv[3]);
         char line[N], line2[N];
         int l,r, ok;
         while (fgets(line, N, fp1)) {
             int i=0;
             while (line[i]!='\0') {
                 l=r=0;
                 ok=1;
                 int k=0, j=i;
                 while(j<sizeof(s1)){
                     if (line[j]!=s1[k]) {
                         ok=0;
                     }
                     k++;
                 }
                 if (ok) {
                     replace(line, i, j, s2);
                 }
                 i++;
             }
             fputs(line, fp2);
         }

         while (fgets(line2, N, fp2)) {
             puts(line2);
         }
         return 0;
     }

     void replace(char *s, int l, int r, char *s2){
         char line[N], line2[N];
         strncat(line, s, l);
         strcat(line, s2);
         int k=0, j=r+1;
         while (s[j]!='\0') {
             line2[k]=s[j];
             k++;
             j++;
         }
         strcat(line, line2);
         strcpy(s, line);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal you can compile you code with the command `gcc myfile.c` (check the man of gcc if you need flags).

Once it is compiled, you can execute the executive file, which is named a.out (if you didn't rename it), by typing `./a.out`. This will execute your program.

If you need arguments in your main you can simply type : `./a.out myArgv1 myArgv2` , and so on.
Your arguments can be strings, filenames, ect...
This works for Linux and MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check that you have installed gcc (C compiler). Write:
`gcc --version` and you should see your version.
Once you are sure about having gcc, compile your program:

`gcc yourfile.c -o nameofexecutable` Note: With that option you can choose whatever the name you want for your executable file.

Finally, execute your file with the desired arguments.

`./nameofexecutable argument1 argument2 argument3` Note: Obviously you can introduce 0, 1, 2 or whatever list of arguments.

Comment: Segmentation fault is not because of how you are executing it, it is probably because of your code. There might be some little error. I recommend you use gdb (C Debugger) so you can execute line after line until you find the problem.